# Is it possible to autoscroll an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe, autoscroll

An autoscroll sample is something like this http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

I wish to autoscroll the content of an iframe whose contents have width beyond the browser width. Is this something which can be achieved thru query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your iframe content inside a `<marquee>`, might be not perfect, but working.

The best option probably would be to make a slider inside your iframe, or animate with jQuery inside it, make sur you hide the scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found an answer, http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/  but I need to tinker with it to make the function work same as the sample

Comment: Good luck with that! Don't forget to validate the answer if it helped you out... :)